# Tablet for reading and writing notes

Tags: tablet

I'm looking for a tablet that is optimal for reading PDFs and making handwritten notes on them. I would like a large screen: some of the PDFs are in A4 format and they should be shown in something that is not too far from their natural size. And it should come with a pen that can be slid into the tablet itself. And writing with it should work very, very well!

Except for this, I don't need very strong specifications or special features. I would also like to watch movies on it, but I'm not very demanding w.r.t. the quality, so I think pretty much any tablet would satisfy my needs in that area.

How cheaply can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

In case it's of interest to anyone, I went with a Samsung Galaxy Tab A with S Pen, 16 GB Wifi Tablet 10.1 Inch, and I am quite happy with the choice.

Answer (score 0):

Lenovo Yoga Tab 3, it also supports any pen technology. You can scribble and write on its screen. Good for reading, watching and writing.